# Can two different release active at the same time in Googleplay?

Tags: android, google-play

We want to upgrade our minSdkVersion for our App, but if we roll-out the minSdkVersion-upgraded App to googleplay and if the user with lower Android api level phone uninstall the App, he wouldn't install our App any more. Am i right?

From [this page](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks#HowItWorks), I know I could publish different APKs for different versions of Android. This is a little different from what I want.

The googleplay can only one AAB active in production with 100% rolled-out. So if I upload one AAB **without** lower-minSdkVersion feature and roll-out it 100%, then the previous lower-minSdkVersion App is not visible to the user. Do I understand it correctly?

What I want to do is that I roll-out a  lower-minSdkVersion AAB and not need to maintain it anymore in later AAB release. Maintaining is a nightmare:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Play console screen shot]

Just add the previous bundle by pressing this include button while you are creating a new release.

Comment: where is the "include", I cannot see it when I'm uploading AAB...

Comment: It should be just below the upload area. Can you share the screenshot of your page?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. yes, you are right, there is the include below the previous bundle. Thanks